# how to get addressable labels assigned in the addressable window within script

Tags: unity-game-engine

With the new addressable introduced in Unity we can assign each asset that falls into a different group with a label in the Addressable window.

[image]

Is there a way to get these labels in the script?

Comment: Maybe try asking in the [forums](https://forum.unity.com/forums/addressables.156/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a bit of time to figure out this.
Labels seem to be stored as  `LabelTable` list in;

```
UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.AddressableAssetSettingsDefaultObject.Settings;
```

However the list is private. In the script we can;

- add a label to `LabelTable` by calling `AddressableAssetSettingsDefaultObject.Settings.AddLabel()`
- remove a label from the `LabelTable`by calling `AddressableAssetSettingsDefaultObject.Settings.RemoveLabel()`

Other than these two methods there are no other means of accessing `LabelTable`

One way we can get around this by using `System.Reflection` which would allow us to bypass non-public access to `LabelTable`.

```
AddressableAssetSettings settings = UnityEditor.AddressableAssets.AddressableAssetSettingsDefaultObject.Settings;
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
object labelTable = settings.GetType().GetProperty("labelTable", bindingFlags).GetValue(settings);
List<string> labelNames = (List<string>)labelTable.GetType().GetProperty("labelNames", bindingFlags).GetValue(labelTable);
```

Surely using `System.Reflection` will raise eyebrows since we are trying to access a non-public member. However, on this occasion, I believe the unity team didn't think this through. There should be a way of reading these labels so that we can remove, add depending on what we have on the list

Answer (score 1):

There is a brute way to do it. You can modify file responsible for group data. Parse AddressableAssetsData\AssetGroups[your_group_name].asset file and add labels manually to m_SerializedLabels field.
Example:
Change this:
m_GUID: 5f0bfe8eea13575418016bf83784f8e0
m_Address: SomeAssetAddress
m_ReadOnly: 0
m_SerializedLabels: []

to this:
m_GUID: 5f0bfe8eea13575418016bf83784f8e0
m_Address: DefaultAvatarAnimation
m_ReadOnly: 0
m_SerializedLabels:
- label1
- label2
etc

Comment: upvoted... but surely there must be a less hacky way??